# Proxy web interface with help traefik

Tags: docker, docker-compose, webserver, devops, traefik

I'm trying to proxy the pgAdmin web interface using segment URLs. But I have some problems with this.

When I'm accessing the browser with the following URL -> http://localhost/pgadmin, it redirects me to the following URL -> http://localhost/login?next=%2F. This is the internal routing of pgAdmin.

I want routing to be next http://localhost/pgadmin/login?next=%2F.

Could you tell me how can I achieve this.

Here is an example of my docker-compose configuration

```
version: '3.7'

services:

  traefik:
   image: traefik:v2.2
   container_name: traefik
   restart: always
   networks:
            applications_network:
                ipv4_address: 172.20.1.1
   ports:
    - "80:80"
    - "8080:8080"
   command: 
    - "--api.insecure=true --providers.docker"
    - "--api.insecure=true"
    - "--providers.docker=true"
    - "--providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false"
    - "--entrypoints.web.address=:80"
    - "--log.level=debug"
   volumes:
    - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"


  pgAdmin4:
   image: dpage/pgadmin4:latest
   container_name: pgAdmin4
   restart: always
   networks:
            applications_network:
                ipv4_address: 172.20.2.1
   ports:
    - "15432:80"
   environment:
    PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: "admin@test.com"
    PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: "postgres"
   labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.pgAdmin4.rule=Host(`localhost`)"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.pgAdmin4-prefix.stripprefix.prefixes=/pgadmin"
      - "traefik.http.routers.pgAdmin4.middlewares=pgAdmin4-prefix"
      - "traefik.http.routers.pgAdmin4.entrypoints=web"
      - "traefik.http.routers.pgAdmin4.service=pgAdmin4"
      - "traefik.http.services.pgAdmin4.loadbalancer.server.port=80"


networks:
    applications_network:
        name: applications_network
        ipam:
            driver: default
            config:
                - subnet: 172.20.0.0/16
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you say `I want routing to be next http://localhost/pgadmin/login?next=%2F.`, do you mean you don't want the redirect to take place?

Comment: Yes, I want this URL http://localhost/pgadmin/ to be static, and all that comes after /pgadmin/ were segments of pgAdmin itself.